# How do I get the close event of a stage in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, stage

In JavaFX, how can I get the event if a user clicks the Close Button(X) (right most top cross) a stage?

I want my application to print a debug message when the window is closed. (`System.out.println("Application Close by click to Close Button(X)")`)

```
@Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
       root.getChildren().add(btn);
       Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
       primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();

       // Any Event Handler
       //{
       System.out.println("Application(primaryStage) Closed by click to Close Button(X)");
       //}
   }
```

Answer (score 18):

I got the answer for this question

```
stage.setOnHiding(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

         @Override
         public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
             Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     System.out.println("Application Closed by click to Close Button(X)");
                     System.exit(0);
                 }
             });
         }
     });
```

Comment: It"s `stage.setOnCloseRequest(...)`.

Comment: .setOnHiding worked for me and .setOnCloseRequest did not

Comment: Are there any way to close window without `System.exit` call?

Comment: `setOnCloseRequest` will only be called when there's external request to close the window, I assume this means manually clicking close button. This also means it won't be triggered by `stage.close()` calls.

Answer (score 13):

Another method for achieving the same effect, but remains more consistent with the way you start your application is to override stop();

According to the JavaFX documentation, the lifecycle of an instance of an Application is as follows:

> The JavaFX runtime does the following, in order, whenever an application is launched:
>
> 1. Constructs an instance of the specified Application class
> 2. Calls the init() method
> 3. Calls the start(javafx.stage.Stage) method
> 4. Waits for the application to finish, which happens when either of the following occur:
>
>    - the application calls Platform.exit()
>    - the last window has been closed and the implicitExit attribute on Platform is true
> 5. Calls the stop() method

As a result you simply override stop()

```
@Override
public void stop(){
    System.out.println("Stage is closing");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
      public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
          System.out.println("Stage is closing");
      }
  });
```